# how to group values inside an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

i have this situation `$result`:

```
[result] => Array
    (
        [Jeffrey] => Array
            (
                [date] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1294439732
                        [1] => 1294074456
                        [2] => 1295041663
                    )
                [amt] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 6.90
                        [1] => 19.50
                        [2] => 19.50
                    )
            )
        [John] => Array
            (
                [date] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1294439732
                        [1] => 1294074456
                        [2] => 1295041663
                    )
                [amt] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 6.90
                        [1] => 19.50
                        [2] => 19.50
                    )
            )
)
```

what i am trying to accomplish is this:

```
[result] => Array
    (
        [Jeffrey] => Array
            (
                [date] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1294439732
                           [amt] => Array(
                             [0] => 6.90
                         )
                        [1] => 1294074456
                           [amt] => Array(
                             [0] => 19.50
                         )
                        [2] => 1295041663
                           [amt] => Array(
                             [0] => 19.50
                         )
                    )
            )
        [John] => Array
            (
                [date] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1294439732
                           [amt] => Array(
                             [0] => 6.90
                         )
                        [1] => 1294074456
                           [amt] => Array(
                             [0] => 19.50
                         )
                        [2] => 1295041663
                           [amt] => Array(
                             [0] => 19.50
                         )
                    )
            )
)
```

i might have got the array formatting wrong, but the idea is that each `date` has a corespondent `amt` and i want that amount inside the date

not sure how to proceed to reorganize this array to look like that.
$result['date']
i'm thinking i need to do a foreach loop and put together `$result['date'] and $result['amt']`.

anyone has any ideas?

thanks

Comment: You should add the appropriate language tag...

Comment: Please retag with the appropriate language -- this will help expose it to a more appropriate audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($results as $user => $data) {
    $newArray[$user] = array();
    $newArray[$user]['date'] = array();
    for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($results[$user]['date']); $x++) {
        $newArray[$user]['date'][$x] = array();
        array_push($newArray[$user]['date'][$x], $results[$user]['date'][$x]);
        array_push($newArray[$user]['date'][$x], array('amt' => array($results[$user]['amt'][$x])));
    }
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Not sure why you want all those arrays especially the array inside of amt since there is only 1 element.

Comment: i get ` Cannot use string offset as an array` at line 7 for the first `array_push`

Comment: i think it's complaining about that `[$x]`

Comment: @Patrioticcow please post the $results array var you are using. The one I made based off of your OP worked without errors.

Comment: You flagged a question asking about a context-free grammar as "off topic." Theoretical CS question are on topic on SO until further notice. I didn't decline your flag because the question wasn't that great, but just an FYI.

Comment: i got to the solution, but i had a good start. thanks @jostster

Comment: @jostster I am referring to a different question.